# How to access IMEI number on Android 10?

Tags: android, android-10.0, imei

Google has restricted the old way to get IMEI number on Android devices starting from Android 10, but my app has always relied on it to validate users and make sure they are unique without bothering them with Username stuff.

Other alternatives like advertising id and Android id did not work for me, as they might change if the user made a device format or factory reset.

Is there any other way to get IMEI number in Android 10?

**EDIT:** I need the IMEI number specifically from non device or profile owner app; Not SSAID, Advertising ID, nor any other number!

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have read the article already. I still wonder, if there is any work around to get the IMEI number specifically as a non device or profile owner app!

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Android 10, apps must have the **READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE** privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number.

as per [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)

Comment: Is there any work around for non device or profile owner apps?